# Windows Embedded and Compact

Tags: drivers, embedded, windows-embedded-7

Does anyone know if standard USB device drivers for Windows 7/XP would install on Windows Embedded Standard 7 or Compact 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applications and drivers for Windows 7 can work on Windows Embedded Standard 7 without difficult, expensive, and time-consuming porting effort

Per: http://www.microsoft.com/windowsembedded/en-us/evaluate/windows-embedded-standard-7.aspx

Comment: Thanks - do you mean "WITH difficult..." or "WITHOUT difficult..."

Comment: It says -no- porting is required, so without difficulty.